# Join query in multiple database

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, join

I have a database with millions of records, because of some issues we are planning to put some specific tables into a different (new) database.

If I put my tables in to a different database (on the same server) and apply joins between the current and new databases, will there be a performance hit (compared to joins within a database)?

Comment: Perhaps http://dba.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Why not do some performance tests on such a scenario yourself?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the raw performance is not different other than the query optimiser only work for one table within one DB at a time. So your query becomes two optimised queries, with the join between the database in the latter steps. This may result in highly un-optimised queries in some cases, in other cases no difference

Just get an SSD and forget it

Comment: can you please provide me any link where i can read more about working of query optimizer on multiple db query.

Comment: Just run your queries through query analyser as see what happens. Either way a decent SSD is cheaper and quicker at fixing perf prob!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there will be no performance hit. But with sql server 2008 you can use filegroups that will achieve the same thing as you try to achieve by separating the tables. You can also put them on different disks so that will be helpful performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming all other things are equal, then I do not believe that a JOIN between mutliple databases vs a single database should not incur a performance penalty in of itself.

However, there are too many variables and questions that your proposal raises.  Are you doing any normalizing?  How will the new tables be indexed?  Foreign keys?  Is this a high-transactional server/database?  How are your physical files set up before & after?  Things like disk I/O, transaction logging, etc. could all play a factor.

Comment: The first sentence contains double negation, and I believe incorrectly so? Also, "do not believe" is not really great for an answer - do you know that? Have you done comparisons?